# Failure to build QT5 5.12.3 on Raspberry Pi zero

Tags: qt, make

Following the instructions in https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-512-raspberry-pi,:

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.xz
tar xf qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.x
```

z
    git clone https://github.com/oniongarlic/qt-raspberrypi-configuration.git

> cd into the clone repository and run (adjust DESTDIR in case your Qt
>   sources are extracted somewhere else):

```
cd qt-raspberrypi-configuration && make install DESTDIR=../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3

apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential libfontconfig1-dev libdbus-1-dev libfreetype6-dev libicu-dev libinput-dev libxkbcommon-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libglib2.0-dev libraspberrypi-dev
```

So for running the `configure` file i entered this command to terminal:
    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/llvm-3.8

```
 sudo PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig \
    ../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/configure -platform linux-rpi-g++ \
    -v \
    -opengl es2 -eglfs \
    -no-gtk \
    -opensource -confirm-license -release \
    -reduce-exports \
    -force-pkg-config \
    -nomake examples -no-compile-examples \
    -skip qtwayland \
    -skip qtwebengine \
    -no-feature-geoservices_mapboxgl \
    -qt-pcre \
    -no-pch \
    -ssl \
    -evdev \
    -system-freetype \
    -fontconfig \
    -glib \
    -prefix /opt/Qt5.12 \
    -qpa eglfs \
    -qt-xcb
```

I have gone until the configure process so get this output:

```
rying source 0 (type pkgConfig) of library pulseaudio ...
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --exists --silence-errors libpulse '>=' 0.9.10 libpulse-mainloop-glib
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libpulse '>=' 0.9.10 libpulse-mainloop-glib
> 10.0
> 10.0
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs-only-L libpulse '>=' 0.9.10 libpulse-mainloop-glib
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs-only-l libpulse '>=' 0.9.10 libpulse-mainloop-glib
> -lpulse-mainloop-glib -lpulse -lglib-2.0
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --cflags libpulse '>=' 0.9.10 libpulse-mainloop-glib
> -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include
+ cd /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/config.tests/pulseaudio && /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared use_gold_linker warn_off console single_arch" 'QMAKE_USE += pulseaudio' 'QMAKE_LIBS_PULSEAUDIO = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpulse.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so' 'QMAKE_INCDIR_PULSEAUDIO = /usr/include/glib-2.0 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include' 'QMAKE_DEFINES_PULSEAUDIO = _REENTRANT' /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtmultimedia/config.tests/pulseaudio
+ cd /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/config.tests/pulseaudio && MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/make
> g++ -c -pipe -mfpu=vfp -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6zk -O2 -w -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtmultimedia/config.tests/pulseaudio -I. -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-rpi-g++ -o pulseaudio.o /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtmultimedia/config.tests/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.cpp
> g++ -Wl,-O1 -fuse-ld=gold -o pulseaudio pulseaudio.o   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpulse.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so   
 => source accepted.

Trying source 0 (type pkgConfig) of library libresourceqt5 ...
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --exists --silence-errors libresourceqt5
pkg-config did not find package.
  => source produced no result.

Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Build type: linux-rpi-g++ (arm, CPU features: <none>)
Compiler: gcc 6.3.0
Configuration: use_gold_linker enable_new_dtags largefile shared rpath release c++11 c++14 concurrent dbus reduce_exports stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++14
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using gold linker ...................... yes
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. no
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. no
  Build parts ............................ libs tools
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  udev ................................... yes
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ yes
  GLib ................................... yes
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes
  DTLS ................................... yes
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. yes
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... yes
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  EGL .................................... yes
  OpenVG ................................. yes
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ yes
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... yes
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. yes
  tslib .................................. yes
  xkbcommon .............................. yes
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. yes
    XCB Xlib ............................. yes
    EGL on X11 ........................... yes
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. yes
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... yes
    EGLFS GBM ............................ yes
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... yes
    EGLFS X11 ............................ yes
  LinuxFB ................................ yes
  VNC .................................... yes
  Mir client ............................. no
  XCB:
    Using system-provided XCB libraries .. no
    XCB XKB .............................. yes
    XCB XInput ........................... yes
    Native painting (experimental) ....... yes
    GL integrations:
      GLX Plugin ......................... no
      EGL-X11 Plugin ..................... yes
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... yes
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. yes
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. yes
  SQLite2 ................................ yes
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... yes
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. yes
  Socket CAN FD .......................... yes
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. no
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. no
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... no
  Linux Crypto API ....................... no
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. no
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... yes
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... yes
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ yes
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. yes
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
Qt Tools:
  QDoc ................................... no

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.

Either ensure that llvm-config is in your PATH environment variable, or set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
On Windows, you must set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the installation path.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/opt/Qt5.12'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
```

and by running `make -j2` i get this output:

```
bcommon.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbrcmEGL /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgthread-2.0.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so   
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: .obj/qxcbwindow.o: file is empty
.obj/qxcbclipboard.o:qxcbclipboard.cpp:function QXcbClipboard::requestor() const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setWindowTitle(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int, QString const&)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::getQtSelectionOwner(): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setWindowTitle(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int, QString const&)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::clientLeader(): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setWindowTitle(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int, QString const&)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::event(QEvent*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::updateSyncRequestCounter()'
.obj/qxcbintegration.o:qxcbintegration.cpp:function QXcbIntegration::createForeignWindow(QWindow*, unsigned int) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::QXcbWindow(QWindow*)'
.obj/qxcbintegration.o:qxcbintegration.cpp:function QXcbIntegration::createForeignWindow(QWindow*, unsigned int) const: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for QXcbForeignWindow'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
.obj/qxcbintegration.o:qxcbintegration.cpp:function QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::QXcbWindow(QWindow*)'
.obj/qxcbintegration.o:qxcbintegration.cpp:function QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::create()'
.obj/qxcbkeyboard.o:qxcbkeyboard.cpp:function QXcbKeyboard::handleKeyEvent(unsigned int, QEvent::Type, unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned int, bool): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::updateNetWmUserTime(unsigned int)'
.obj/qxcbscreen.o:qxcbscreen.cpp:function QXcbVirtualDesktop::QXcbVirtualDesktop(QXcbConnection*, xcb_screen_t*, int): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::windowTitle(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int)'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbBackingStoreImage::setClip(QRegion const&): error: undefined reference to 'qRegionToXcbRectangleList(QRegion const&)'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore::initXRenderMode(): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::visualId() const'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore::initXRenderMode(): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::visualId() const'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore::QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore(QWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::visualId() const'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore::QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore(QWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setParentRelativeBackPixmap()'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbBackingStore::flush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::needsSync() const'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbBackingStore::flush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::updateSyncRequestCounter()'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbBackingStore::composeAndFlush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, QPlatformTextureList*, bool): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::needsSync() const'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbBackingStore::composeAndFlush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, QPlatformTextureList*, bool): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::updateSyncRequestCounter()'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore::recreateImage(QXcbWindow*, QSize const&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::xcbScreen() const'
.obj/qxcbbackingstore.o:qxcbbackingstore.cpp:function QXcbSystemTrayBackingStore::recreateImage(QXcbWindow*, QSize const&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::xcbScreen() const'
.obj/qxcbnativeinterface.o:qxcbnativeinterface.cpp:function dumpNativeWindowsRecursion(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int, int, QTextStream&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::windowTitle(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int)'
.obj/qxcbnativeinterface.o:qxcbnativeinterface.cpp:function QXcbNativeInterface::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setWmWindowTypeStatic(QWindow*, QFlags<QXcbWindowFunctions::WmWindowType>)'
.obj/qxcbnativeinterface.o:qxcbnativeinterface.cpp:function QXcbNativeInterface::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setWmWindowRoleStatic(QWindow*, QByteArray const&)'
.obj/qxcbnativeinterface.o:qxcbnativeinterface.cpp:function QXcbNativeInterface::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::setWindowIconTextStatic(QWindow*, QString const&)'
.obj/qxcbnativeinterface.o:qxcbnativeinterface.cpp:function QXcbNativeInterface::platformFunction(QByteArray const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::visualIdStatic(QWindow*)'
.obj/qxcbdrag.o:qxcbdrag.cpp:function QXcbDrag::move(QPoint const&, QFlags<Qt::MouseButton>, QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifier>): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::windowTitle(QXcbConnection const*, unsigned int)'
.obj/qxcbconnection_xi2.o:qxcbconnection_xi2.cpp:function QXcbConnection::xi2ProcessTouch(void*, QXcbWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::xcbScreen() const'
.obj/qxcbconnection_xi2.o:qxcbconnection_xi2.cpp:function QXcbConnection::xi2ProcessTouch(void*, QXcbWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::doStartSystemMoveResize(QPoint const&, int)'
.obj/qbackingstore_x11.o:qbackingstore_x11.cpp:function QXcbNativeBackingStore::flush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::needsSync() const'
.obj/qbackingstore_x11.o:qbackingstore_x11.cpp:function QXcbNativeBackingStore::flush(QWindow*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbWindow::updateSyncRequestCounter()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.xcb_qpa_lib:260: recipe for target '../../../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.12.3' failed
make[6]: *** [../../../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.12.3] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb'
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'sub-xcb_qpa_lib-pro-make_first-ordered' failed
make[5]: *** [sub-xcb_qpa_lib-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb'
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'sub-xcb-make_first' failed
make[4]: *** [sub-xcb-make_first] Error 2
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
( test -e Makefile.eglfs-plugin || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile.eglfs-plugin /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/eglfs-plugin.pro ) && make -f Makefile.eglfs-plugin 
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
cd deviceintegration/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/deviceintegration.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration'
cd eglfs_kms_support/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_support/eglfs_kms_support.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
cd eglfs_x11/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_x11/eglfs_x11.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_x11'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_x11'
cd eglfs_brcm/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_brcm/eglfs_brcm.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_support'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_support'
cd eglfs_emu/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_emu/eglfs_emu.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_brcm'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_brcm'
cd eglfs_kms/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms/eglfs_kms.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_emu'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_emu'
cd eglfs_kms_egldevice/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/pi/Desktop/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_egldevice/eglfs_kms_egldevice.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms'
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_egldevice'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_egldevice'
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
Makefile:104: recipe for target 'sub-platforms-make_first' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src/plugins'
Makefile:725: recipe for target 'sub-plugins-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase/src'
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/qt-raspberrypi-configuration/qtbase'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

My question link via Qt forum:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/103934/failure-to-build-qt5-5-12-3-on-raspberry-pi-zero

So, what can i do to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to build Qt5.12 on a pi-4.

I used the following script cobbled together from a couple of sources:

```
# Qt 5.12 build
# See: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code
# Different approach: https://github.com/plexydesk/cross-compile-tools/blob/master/build-qt5

# Dependencies:    
# does not work on raspian
#sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
#sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default

sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake zlib1g-dev libgl1-mesa-dev gcc g++ graphviz doxygen gettext bzr
sudo apt-get install clang
sudo apt-get install *libclang*
sudo apt-get install libllvm*

sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev 
sudo apt-get install build-essential perl python git
sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev
sudo apt-get install flex bison gperf libicu-dev libxslt-dev ruby
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev libdbus-1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcap-dev libxtst-dev libpulse-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libnss3-dev libasound2-dev libxss-dev libegl1-mesa-dev gperf bison
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev

#get source and configure repository

git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout 5.12
perl init-repository
cd ..

#setup for build
# needed for qdoc - can't get to work on rpi at the moment
# export LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/llvm-9/

# build out of source
mkdir build_qt
cd build_qt
../qt5/configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license

make -j5
make -j5 module-qtscript
sudo make install
cd ..

# https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Creator_from_Git

export PATH=/opt/Qt5.12/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt5.12/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You may need to install more packages then installed by the script for the build to work.

On a Pi-0 reduce the number of cores used to build.

You may have issues around OpenGL/EGL support on the Pi-0.

You will need to increase your swap space as amount of memory is only 512Mb.

Make sure you use a fast decent sized SD card.

Once you have Qt built and installed qtcreator build is straight forward.

**NOTE:** parts of Qt are licenced as GPL so if you are building a commercial app be careful to make sure you avoid these libraries/components.